# Setup a git commit message policy

Tags: git

We would like to ensure that every commit message have a Jira ticket number in the subject. For instance, it should be something like "MA-12: Fixed issue about ...".

I know that this can easily be done on client side using commit-msg hook. But this will not be automatically setup for all developers. Is there any way we could do this on server side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup an [update hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) on the server side, similar [to this script](https://gist.github.com/padcom/3677248) (by [Matthias Hryniszak `padcom`](https://gist.github.com/padcom)):

If the commit message received doesn't respect the right policy, the push will be rejected.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"
result=0

# Make sure we handle the situation when the branch does not exist yet
if ! [ $oldrev = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ] ; then
    excludes=( ^$oldrev )
else
    excludes=( $(git for-each-ref --format '^%(refname:short)' refs/heads/) )
fi

# Get the list of incomming commits
commits=`git rev-list $newrev "${excludes[@]}"`

# For every commit in the list
for commit in $commits
do
  # check the log message for ticket number
  message=`git log --format=%s -1 $commit`
  ticket=`echo "$message" | grep -o "^[A-Z]\{2,3\}-[0-9]\+"`
  if [ "$ticket" = "" ] ; then
    echo "Commit $commit does not start with a ticket number"
    result=1
  fi
done

exit $result
```