# How to restrict push size in Git

Tags: git, gitolite

I have gitolite-admin.

Some times our programmers don't use `.gitignore` file and commit whole directory to the remote repo.

How can I restrict push size in git?

I tried search in git config but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit by changed files amount.
In your config file:

```
repo @all
    -   VREF/COUNT/50   = @all
```

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with git commit.
You need to set up hooks for this job.

[What are some more forceful ways than a .gitignore to keep (force) files out of a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400416/what-are-some-more-forceful-ways-than-a-gitignore-to-keep-force-files-out-of/35400472#35400472)

Your hook will check what you want to do and then will decide if to approve the push or not.

In your hook you will have something like this:

```
# in the hook use this line to get the size of each file
git ls-tree -l
```

[image]

If you want to see the same results in your repository use this:

```
git ls-tree HEAD -l
```

---

### **`How to write hooks`**:

Here is a nice sample how to attrack attention in hooks:
[How to enforce a git commit message policy on local system to prevent pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718771/how-to-enforce-a-git-commit-message-policy-on-local-system-to-prevent-pushing)